# Products are not displayed when simple search on django

Tags: python, django

I do search on Django and faced with a problem: products are not displayed. I dont understand why

views

```
class SearchView(ListView):

    template_name = 'store/products.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search', '')
        if query:
            products = Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query))
        else:
            products = Product.objects.all()
        return products
```

search template

```
<form class="form-inline mb-3" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
<div class="form-group col-8 col-md-10 pl-0">
    <input class="form-control w-100" type="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" name="search">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-4 col-md-2 pl-0">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Найти</button>
</div>
</form>
```

products template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
List
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<body style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
{% for product in products %}
<main class="container mt-3" style="text-align: center; max-width: 500px;">
    <div style="border: 5px solid white; background-color: white;">
        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
            <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" style="width:15vh; height:auto;"><br>
        </a>
        <p style="font-size: 20px">{{ product.name }}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 22px">{{ product.price }} руб.</p>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'cart_add' product.id %}"><br>
            <p style="display: none"></p>
            {{ form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
            {% else %}
            <p></p>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endfor %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

I did the same search and all good. I think problem with templates or models. Most likely the solution will be quite simple, but I can't see it

Comment: Maybe queryset is just empty? Did you try printing it out ?

Comment: Yes, I did it right now. Query not empty

Comment: Why do you assume the queryset is present in the context as `products`? It is not.